# Magento custom package not setting file permissions right

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I made a custom package for Magento, I'm on 1.9.1.0. I did it from Admin package manager. I installed the package from "Magento Connect Manager", it installs without error; the only problem is that my PHP file in the package is installed with "666" permission instead "644", so it won't be run by the PHP processor, because of the faulty permission. Any idea how to fix this?

The file used to make the package had right permissions "644". The syntax of my package.xml file is correct, as far as I can tell:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <name>Magento_Iframe_Finder</name>
    <version>1.4.7.3</version>
    <stability>stable</stability>
    <license uri="http://www.opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0">OSL-3.0</license>
    <channel>community</channel>
    <extends/>
    <summary>Magento iframe finder.</summary>
    <description>Magento iframe finder.</description>
    <notes>Easy to install and use</notes>
    <authors><author><name>John Doe</name><user>auto-converted</user><email>johndoe@gmail.com</email></author></authors>
    <date>2015-12-19</date>
    <time>08:04:22</time>
    <contents><target name="mageweb"><dir name="errors"><file name="iframefinder.php" hash="54abb08163b654dd08635b40220c02e2"/></dir></target></contents>
    <compatible/>
    <dependencies><required><php><min>4.7.1</min><max>6.8.9</max></php></required></dependencies>
</package>
```

Any idea if there's a "switch" that I can add to my "package.xml" file to set the right file permissions to my file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has an answer I found it myself.
Default Magento file permissions are: 777 for directories and 666 for files, in the "Magento Connect Manager" you can change them to 755 and eventually 644 then packages will install correctly.